# C# UI Automation to Test WinForm App that has Google Oauth Login

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, ui-automation, ui-testing

I have a WinForm C# Windows App and I am working on Automation UI Testing with it.

The current problem I have is...

When I do click "Login with Google", it opens Chrome for the OAuth, and return the token back to the app to do the login.

Is there anyway I can simulate those action?

I am new to Visual Studio Automation UI Testing but I have background to work with Selenium and its easy with Web App to enter credential for Google Login

Thanks